# window.onload not waiting until dom ready

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6

Inspite of wrapping the code in app.js in the window.onload function, I keep getting the error

```
Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

triggered by the creation of the HomeView on the index route. The render function of the HomeView tries to set the template to the innerHtml of the el in the render function

```
this.el.innerHTML = this.template();
```

As I'm using some ES6, this code is also tranpsiled using babeljs and placed into one file (bundle.js).

Prior to trying the window.onload function, I used ES6 style dom ready to wrap the code in app.js

```
$(() => {

});
```

How can I really ensure that the dom is ready, or how should I otherwise set the el of the HomeView to a particular dom node?

**app.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.myRouter = new MyRouter();
    $(window).on("hashchange", myRouter.hashChange);     
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})

}
```

**main.js**

```
export class MyRouter extends Router {

    constructor(){
        this.routes = {
            '': 'index'
        }
        this._bindRoutes();
    }
    index(){
        this.loadView(new HomeView());
    }
```

HomeView

```
export class HomeView extends View {
    constructor(){

        $("body").html(this.el);
        this.template = _.template($('#main-template').html());

        this.render();
        super();


    }

    render(){

        this.el.innerHTML = this.template();
```

Comment: You are never setting `this.el` in your `HomeView`. If it's supposed to be set by `View`, then you have to call the parent constructor before you access `this`.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure you should have `this._super()` there somewhere. Also, this has nothing to do with the DOM being loaded or not. `this.el` will have a value whenever it is assigned a value and that is unrelated to the loading of the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `onload`. You are simply accessing a property before it exists.

You are never setting `this.el` in your `HomeView` constructor:

```
$("body").html(this.el);
this.template = _.template($('#main-template').html());
this.render();
```

You are calling `this.render()`, which access `this.el.innerHTML`, but where in these three lines are you setting `this.el`? Nowhere.

If `this.el` supposed to be set by `View`, then you have to call the parent constructor **before** you access `this`:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    $("body").html(this.el);
    this.template = _.template($('#main-template').html());

    this.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(document).ready
```

instead of

```
window.onload
```

Comment: Please explain why this solves the problem. `window.onload` is called even later than `$(document).ready`, so I don't understand why the switch would help.